# While loop with mysql_fetch_array() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Recently in one of my project i wrote the following code for retrieving and print data from database.

```
$query = "select * from tblteachers limit 0, 4";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{   
    while($fetchRow=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))
    {
      echo $fetchRow['id'];
    }
}
```

in the tblteachers table there are 14 row and the query get 4 row but the problem is it print 3 row by missing the first row. that is it print 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @Arif - any chance first row `id` is null/empty ?

Comment: id is auto increment in database. so it must exist.

Comment: Can you paste in the output of the query when you run it from the mysql monitor? An auto_increment field does have to be non-null/primary key to work in MySQL, but if you applied the auto_increment later via `alter table`, after data had already been inserted, there could very well be a record with a null `id`.

Comment: MYSQL_BOTH is useless, it is the second parameter's default value AND it clearly overheads the memory while it loads twice the same data.

Comment: @Marc B - I was test it in MySql's platform. it shows 4 row. but in php it miss the 1 st row.

Comment: How about modifying your inner loop to output more than just the row's id value? try something like `echo 'howdy' . $fetchRow['id']`. If you get four howdy's, you know the loop executed four times. As well, if you're viewing this in a browser, never forget to do a 'view source', as html/browsers will hide many things and make them appear invisible.

Comment: @Marc B - Actually i got 3 howdy. as well the 'view source' also show three row. i can't understand what kind of problem this is

Comment: checking for num_rows before the while is redundant. if there are no rows, execution wont enter while block so the if is completely unneccesary.

Answer (score 1):

you might have used something that moved the pointer.
try adding mysql_data_seek($result,0); before the while statement